# Cron error - Text file busy

Tags: bash, cron

According [this article](https://mensfeld.pl/2013/04/backup-mysql-dump-all-your-mysql-databases-in-separate-files/) I wrote cron job for database backups and if I run it manually on command line it works fine. But if script runs as cron job it fails on error: **Text file busy** Can somebody tell me please what am I doing wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /root/tmp/

TIMESTAMP=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M")
BACKUP_DIR="/root/backups/databases/$TIMESTAMP"
MYSQL=/usr/bin/mysql
MYSQL_USER="root2"
MYSQL_PASSWORD="xxxxxxxxx"
MYSQLDUMP=/usr/bin/mysqldump
 
mkdir -p "$BACKUP_DIR"
 
databases=`$MYSQL --user=$MYSQL_USER -p$MYSQL_PASSWORD -e "SHOW DATABASES;" | grep -Ev "(Database|information_schema|performance_schema)"`
 
for db in $databases; do
  $MYSQLDUMP --force --opt --user=$MYSQL_USER -p$MYSQL_PASSWORD --databases $db | gzip > "$BACKUP_DIR/$db.gz"
done
```

Here is extended error log:

```
+ cd /root/tmp/
++ date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M
+ TIMESTAMP=2020-06-15-19-28
+ BACKUP_DIR=/root/backups/databases/2020-06-15-19-28
+ MYSQL=/usr/bin/mysql
+ MYSQL_USER=root2
+ MYSQL_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
+ MYSQLDUMP=/usr/bin/mysqldump
+ mkdir -p /root/backups/databases/2020-06-15-19-28
++ /usr/bin/mysql --user=root2 -pxxxxxxxxxx -e 'SHOW DATABASES;'
++ grep -Ev '(Database|information_schema|performance_schema)'
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
+ databases='mysql
phpmyadmin
sys
tatrytec'
+ for db in $databases
+ /usr/bin/mysqldump --force --opt --user=root2 -pxxxxxxxxxxx --databases mysql
+ gzip
mysqldump: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
+ for db in $databases
+ /usr/bin/mysqldump --force --opt --user=root2 -pxxxxxxxxxxx --databases phpmyadmin
+ gzip
mysqldump: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
+ for db in $databases
+ gzip
+ /usr/bin/mysqldump --force --opt --user=root2 -pxxxxxxxxxxx --databases sys
mysqldump: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
+ for db in $databases
+ /usr/bin/mysqldump --force --opt --user=root2 -pxxxxxxxxxxx --databases tatrytec
mysqldump: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
+ gzip
```

Comment: Aty whaat line do you get that error? Try adding `set -x` just after the shebang to get full debug of the script if you don't know.

Comment: Where should I add set -x? What is shebang?

Comment: Ok I know what is shebang but I dont know if to add set -x on the same line or on the next line.

Comment: Insert it on the next line.

Comment: Are you aware that `cron` jobs don't have the same runtime environment as "run manually"? `env| sort;set` in both environments will be informative.

Comment: set -x did not help. Still the same simple message Text file busy. What is the difference between cron job env and console env? Both running as the same user. Am I missing something what can be the reason of this error message?

Comment: Cron job looks like: 
***/2 * * * * /root/custom-scripts/backups/databases.sh 2>> /var/log/cron/backups/databases.log** Is it ok?

Comment: So as I modified cron job to ***/2 * * * * bash ...** it started to log extended message. I edited the question and add extended log

Comment: Ok so as I added bash before cron job declaration error is gone.